# Purchased Domain with a Company that No Longer Exists

Tags: domains, purchase

I purchased a domain through a company that has ceased function, but I need access to be able to move the domain and utilize my property.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You mean their website is down and there is no way to log in to an admin interface ?

Most likely we are talking about a reseller, then you need to find out who the upstream registrar is (do a whois lookup) and explain the problem to them. Quite possibly, if the reseller has gone AWOL, they may be able to move the domain name to their own system and they just take over. The odds are that you will not be the only one in this unfortunate situation.

Having access to the admin E-mail address will be critical if they need to verify domain ownership.